# IF statement inside SQL Function

Tags: sql, t-sql

I need to do something like this but I can't manage to find the correct syntax.

```
ALTER function [dbo].[FN_ObtenerArbolEmpresa]    (@empresaID int)
returns table 
as
BEGIN
IF (@empresaID = 0)
  begin
    RETURN select id_empresa_hijo from empresa_x_empresa
  end
ELSE
  begin
  return 
  (
  WITH  temp
      AS (
            -- anchor
          SELECT  id_empresa_hijo, id_empresa_padre
          FROM    empresa_x_empresa with(nolock)
          WHERE   id_empresa_padre = @empresaID
          UNION ALL
            --recursive member
          SELECT  t.id_empresa_hijo, t.id_empresa_padre
          FROM    empresa_x_empresa AS t with(nolock)
                  JOIN temp AS a
                    ON t.id_empresa_padre = a.id_empresa_hijo
         )
  (
  SELECT id_empresa_hijo  FROM temp 
  union 
  select @empresaID
  )
 end
```

Actually I just want to avoid the recursion when @empresaID = 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the table you want to return. 
For Example:

```
ALTER  FUNCTION [dbo].[Split](@sText varchar(8000), @sDelim varchar(20) = '')
RETURNS @retArray TABLE (idx smallint Primary Key, value varchar(2000))
AS
BEGIN
...
```

Comment: thanks! i tried before that but forgot to insert values on the @retArray table.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing an END at the end of your Query. The you have one to end the function, but not one to end the ELSE statement.

Comment: The first syntax error appears in the first "BEGIN" after "as"